# confusing java data structures

Tags: java

Maybe the title is not appropriate but I couldn't think of any other at this moment. My question is what is the difference between LinkedList and ArrayList or HashMap and [THashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/THashMap.html) .

Is there a tree structure already for Java(ex:AVL,red-black) or balanced or not balanced(linked list). If this kind of question is not appropriate for SO please let me know I will delete it. thank you

Comment: ArrayList/LinkedList difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist

Comment: Fixed link to THashMap... there were "..." in place of several directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are implementations of the `List` abstraction.  The first holds the elements of the list in an internal array which is automatically reallocated as necessary to make space for new elements.  The second constructs a doubly linked list of holder cells, each of which refers to a list element.  While the respective operations have identical semantics, they differ considerably in performance characteristics.  For example:

- The `get(int)` operation on an `ArrayList` takes constant time, but it takes time proportional to the length of the list for a `LinkedList`.
- Removing an element via the `Iterator.remove()` takes constant time for a `LinkedList`, but it takes time proportional to the length of the list for an `ArrayList`.

The `HashMap` and `THashMap` are both implementations of the `Map` abstraction that are use hash tables.  The difference is in the form of hash table data structure used in each case.  The `HashMap` class uses *closed addressing* which means that each bucket in the table points to a separate linked list of elements.  The `THashMap` class uses *open addressing* which means that elements that hash to the same bucket are stored in the table itself.  The net result is that `THashMap` uses less memory and is faster than `HashMap` for most operations, but is much slower if you need the map's set of key/value pairs.

For more detail, read a good textbook on data structures.  Failing that, look up the concepts in Wikipedia.  Finally, take a look at the source code of the respective classes.

Comment: you answer is very good indeed, which book would you recommend me to read?

Answer (score 2):

Read the [API docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for the classes you have mentioned. The [collections tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) also explains the differences fairly well.

`java.util.TreeMap` is based on a red-black tree.

Comment: tnx I wrote black-white sorry about that I meant to write red-black

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the lists:

Both comply with the [List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, but their implementation is different, and they differ in the efficiency of some of their operations.

ArrayList is a list stored internally as an array. It has the advantage of [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access), but a single item addition is not guaranteed to run in constant time. Also, removal of items is inefficient.

A LinkedList is implemented as a doubly connected [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). It does not support random access, but removing an item while iterating through it is efficient.

Comment: `single item addition is not guaranteed to run in constant time` - you mean inserting item into ArrayList? I'm not trying to correct you just to verify what you meant. thank you, question if that is the case insertion/deletion vs search/lookup, is it possible to combine those two strenghts and use them when you require certain operation. Ex: create LinkedList list, iterate and trough it and add/delete elements, but if you need to find certain element create new Arraylist with elements of LinkedList(copy them to ArrayList) and perfrom search, is that a good idea?

Comment: @London: Addition of an item to an ArrayList when it has a full capacity requires allocating a new array, and copying the contents. When this happens, the operation is expensive. However, due to the  the way the array is expanded (geometrically), the average cost of an addition for a long sequence of additions is still constant.

Regarding your idea: this doesn't seem to be a beneficial. When you copy the contents it takes linear time, so you could have searched the k-Th item inefficiently in the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, both (LinkedList and ArrayList) are the lists. But they have defferent inner realization.

Comment: `they have different inner realization` - I'm after this , can you provide more details please?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

But both realize List interface.